# Join multiple informative/descriptive database queries

Tags: mysql, join

I need to join two database results, first:

```
DESCRIBE my_table
```

which gives me all columns with data types, and:

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM my_table
```

which gives me the ***index names*** for each column that may have one. I need to join them on `show_indexes.Column_name = describe.Field` so that I get pretty much the same as DESCRIBE but now additionally with index names (or `NULL` if it does not have an index) as opposed to just `PRI` or `MUL` etc. Joining these two results as you would do with two `SELECTS` does not seem to work.

Is this even possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve it from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

1-Show indexes equivalent

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' and TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

2-Describe equivalent

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS `Field`, COLUMN_TYPE AS `Type`, IS_NULLABLE AS `NULL`, 
   COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS `Extra` FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

3-Then formulate your `JOIN` query as you want, this is an eg.:

```
    SELECT s.*, c.*
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' and TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
) as s
RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS `Field`, COLUMN_TYPE AS `Type`, IS_NULLABLE AS `NULL`, 
       COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS `Extra`
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
) as c
ON s.COLUMN_NAME = c.Field
```

Comment: I find that this omits those columns that do not have a index

Comment: it's just an eg., that depends on your JOIN type, chose LEFT or RIGHT

Comment: Your're right with the old query (one single row only). I updated the 3rd point with 2 simple sub-query and tested it out, it works in my machine. :)

Comment: Yep, that works but it takes me up to 10 seconds on my table (couple thousand rows) so I guess I'll have to find an alternative approach

Comment: Also I suspect that the time spent calculating this query does not depend strictly on the number of rows in the respective table but on the size and number of all tables in the database so this might really not be very effective way to do it